# How to restart batch file itself?

Tags: command-line, batch

How to restart batch itself automatically?

If the filename of batch changed,

```
start <fixedbatchfilename>
```

must fail because though the filename changes, the command doesn't.

Is there a feasible way, like

```
start <autogetbatchfilenameitself> ?
```

Comment: why would the file name change?

Comment: @Keltari Maybe end-user will change the filename, so the batch file will become invalid

Comment: "you cant fix stupid" - Ron White

Comment: @Keltari I just want my batch file be valid even if my end-user change the batchfile name

Comment: Just assume they wont change the name - and why would they?  There are things beyond controlling, or worth the effort to try and control.  If they *do* change the name for some unknown reason, fix it, and they wont do it again

Comment: If it's the only batch file in the folder, then you could have a command that executes the batch file in the folder. Or you could put the batch file somewhere obscure, and they run the shortcut. IF they change the name of the shortcut it won't matter.

Comment: and you may be able to change the permissions so they can't change the filename. not quite sure how off hand, though not really a batch question is then a plain windows question. You could have a batch file whose name they won't change, that creates a bat file, echo line1> batfile  echo line2>>batfile e.t.c.

Comment: @barlop THX for giving me an idea... Here is the [pseudocode/c] : `int main (int argc, char* argv[])` and then `system(start argv[0])`

Comment: but something will have to pass that exe file its parameter. By the way, I just realised, if they rename the bat file, they might still run it fine, by double clicking what they renamed it to. a bit like if they rename a shortcut they can still double click the shortcut

Comment: if the batch file is the only one in a folder, here is a bit of batch file code that grabs the path and filename of that file, regardless of its name.  `C:\crp\aaa\ff>for /f %f in ('dir /s/b c:\crp\aaa\ff') do echo %f <ENTER>`    Now whatever the bat file in `c:\crp\aaa\ff` is called, it will get echoed. you can change echo %f to set file=%f   then refer to the file by %file% like start %file%   And by the way, when using start it's better to do start "" filename  otherwise if the filename/path has a space in it, and you put quotes around the filename, then it won't work.

Comment: Also on the subject of restarting a batch file generally, you can put a label at the top like :begin  then a line anywhere that says goto begin

Comment: @barlop Appriciate all your ideas. I chose _Putting the batch file somewhere obscure, and they run the shortcut._ as my last solution. Great ideas. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can call `%0` in the same directory to call the batch itself again.

Here is a little batch-file to see the variables for yourself:

```
@echo off
echo Filename exactly as called: %0
echo Driveletter:                %~d0
echo Path:                       %~p0
echo Filename:                   %~n0
echo Extension:                  %~x0
echo Complete:                   %~d0%~p0%~n0%~x0
```

Example:

```
echo The following will cause this to loop until Ctrl+C is pressed:
%0
```

Or:

```
echo The following will cause this to loop until Ctrl+C is pressed:
%~d0%~p0%~n0%~x0
```

Comment: wow, powerful internal command, THX!

Comment: Edited it a bit. The `%0` always works great but the `%CD%` i suggested was for the current directory, not the directory of the batch itself. `%d0` is driveletter and `%p0` is the path to the batch. But you get the idea. This is all doable in the batch itself. You can find lots more of these goodies [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx).

Comment: (1) `%~f0` seems to be equivalent to ``%~d0%~p0%~n0%~x0`` and, obviously, is much shorter. (2) The `%0` solution may fail if the batch file does a `cd`.  Your second solution (or `%~f0`) is better in that case.

Comment: The problem I have with these solutions is that it doesn't actually completely restart it. It's still remember set variables and possibly other things that I'd love to have the option to just completely restart as if I exited the script and manually started it again.

For example, if I have a script that updates one of the script files. I might want to have it completely restart the script to prevent errors. Currently I have it shut itself down and wait for a manual restart.

Comment: @Brent In that case you could do `start /B %0`. It will start the same batch file in the same window but without variables (in a new process). But it might be better to unset your variable at the correct point (and keep flow in the batch itself or call itself again). Even better is to use `setlocal` and `endlocal` at the correct points to isolate the variable to that specific part of code.

Comment: setlocal and endlocal sounds like a good idea. I am worried about restarting the script after the script has been copied over, like an automated update to the script itself. I will give it a try, but I worry that the copy process replacing some of the code may cause errors without a clean restart of the script.

Answer (score 0):

`start "" "%~f0"` OR `start "title of batch window" "%~f0"`

To restart a batch file use:

`start "" "%~f0"
exit`

This will start your batch file from within your batch file, regardless of file name or location, so long as the name or location has not changed during batch operation, IE after batch has started and before code: (`start "" "%~f0"`) has had a chance to execute.

> Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like "My Script" or just a pair of empty quotes ""
>   According to the Microsoft documentation, the *title* is optional, but depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

source: https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Comment: What advantage does this have over the five-year-old answer?

Comment: the other answer gave users the knowledge to build a working answer for themselves, not the answer itself. As a relatively new user to writing cmd batch files I struggled to wright code that would work as intended as I lacked simple knowledge like using quotation marks around fully qualified path names.

Comment: What are you talking about?  ``%0`` and ``%~d0%~p0%~n0%~x0`` ***are*** complete, ready-to-use solutions.  OK, you made the *trivial* improvement of replacing ``%~d0%~p0%~n0%~x0`` with ``%~f0``, which seems to be equivalent.  Trivial abbreviations do not qualify as new answers.  The big change you introduced was the `start` command, but *why?*  You can run a batch file just by saying its name; you don't need to use `start`.

Comment: I didn't know you could run a batch file just by saying its name, I now understand the first answer, and see that `%0` is the best solution.